# How to write Spring ApplicationContext.xml file?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring3.2.0 releases so i was trying to write below `applicationContext.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

        <!--
                This will automatically locate any and all property files you have
                within your classpath, provided they fall under the META-INF
                directory. The located property files are parsed and their values can
                then be used within application context files in the form of
                ${propertyKey}.
        -->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
</beans>
```

But this xml file giving error in Eclipse Editor

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-
     beans-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 
             2) the document could not be read;
             3) the root element of the 
     document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

So i changed my applicationcontext.xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.0.xsd">

        <!--
                This will automatically locate any and all property files you have
                within your classpath, provided they fall under the META-INF
                directory. The located property files are parsed and their values can
                then be used within application context files in the form of
                ${propertyKey}.
        -->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
</beans>
```

The only changed you will see `xsd` declaration previously i was using `3.0.xsd` and now `3.2.0.xsd` so now eclipse editor issue gone but now when i am running project into Tomcat7 ,run time i am getting below exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
12:20:23.289 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 578; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I am not able to figure out the issue i searched for issue in google but no any solution yet worked, Could any one help me to write the `applicationContext.xml` file?

Comment: I would recommend to download one of the projects from https://github.com/SpringSource and use that applicationContext.xml file

Comment: there are plenty of project but i did not get xml file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

See [Index of schema's](http://www.springframework.org/schema/) for the list of Spring XSDs. The XSD for `spring-beans` can be found in http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/

Comment: Is this any rule to write the applicationContext file?

Comment: The XML must be valid. So you have to reference existing XSDs.

Answer (score 4):

*1) Make sure that you really deploy the `spring-beans-3.2.x.RELEASE.jar`. It contains a `spring.schemas` file in its `META-INF` directory (it must contain the url of the schema location used by you) and a `spring-beans-3.2.xsd` file in `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml` directory.*

2) **The XSD Version is contains only of two parts (major and minor) 3.2 but not 3.2.0!**

BTW: you can use `spring-XXX.xsd` without version, then spring use always the newest version (defined in `spring.schemas` file)

Comment: I am using Maven and in Eclipse Deployment assembly  i have added all the jars

Comment: Worked for me. "without version, then spring use always the newest version" - I didn't know that. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Replace in your context xml file  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd` by `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd`

Answer (score 2):

Change your XML as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <!--
                This will automatically locate any and all property files you have
                within your classpath, provided they fall under the META-INF
                directory. The located property files are parsed and their values can
                then be used within application context files in the form of
                ${propertyKey}.
        -->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
</beans>
```

The XSD versions should be 3.2 not 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

For Listener side JMS, you can adopt this concept:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"  

    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"  
 p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />  

<bean id="listener" class="com.jms.MyMessageListener"></bean>  

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  
 acknowledge="auto">  
   <jms:listener destination="myqueue" ref="listener" method="onMessage"></jms:listener>  
</jms:listener-container>  

</beans>
```

For Sender Side JMS, you can adopt this concept:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"  

    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"  
 p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />  

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">  
 <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></constructor-arg>  
 <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="myqueue"></property>  
</bean>  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jms"></context:component-scan>  

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error n=but its got solved by using below application context files

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

and below is my jar file list,

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```